# twitter bootstrap btn loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a button:

```
<button type="submit" id="subscribe_button" class="btn btn-danger btn-large" data-loading-text="loading stuff...">Subscribe</button>
```

And I am trying to make this button in "loading state" from a form validation script:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
                // do other stuff for a valid form
                $('#results').append('<img src="loading.gif">')
                $('#subscribe_button').button('loading')
                $.post('forms.php', $("#subscribe").serialize(), function(data) {
                    $('#results').html(data);
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#cg1").removeClass('success').removeClass('error')
                    $('#email').val('');
                });
    });
```

Everything works fine until I add following line:

```
$('#subscribe_button').button('loading')
```

Where could be the problem ?

Comment: where did you see the button() command? i don't think it's a valid function

Comment: Here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons

Comment: I found the problem.

I simply had to load jquery-1.7.2.min.js in front of bootstrap.js.

Thanks!